# google calendar access from the command line

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I have activated the google API console https://code.google.com/apis/console and I've created a project, including the OAuth credentials. I've chosen the "desktop application" setting, since this app is going to run outside of the browser, **from the CLI** (and actually only on my computer).

I have also downloaded the client library as described here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/.

I have edited `google-api-php-client/src/config.php` editing the keys `application_name`, `oauth2_client_id`, `oauth2_client_secret`, `oauth2_redirect_uri` and `developer_key` and nothing else.

I have deleted all other services from `services` too.

Now, I have the following app, put together from the samples in the guide:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php';
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php";

session_start();

$apiClient = new apiClient();
$apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
$service = new apiCalendarService($apiClient);


if (isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) {
  $apiClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
} else {
  $token = $apiClient->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token;
}

$event = new Event();
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$start->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$end->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$event->setEnd($end);
$event->setRecurrence(array('RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T100000-07:00'));
$attendee1 = new EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('attendeeEmail');
// ...
$attendees = array($attendee1,
                   // ...
                   );
$event->attendees = $attendees;
$recurringEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);

echo $recurringEvent->getId();
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=<the-key>: (401) Login Required' in /home/flav/projects/.../google-api-php-client/src/io/apiREST.php on line 86

apiServiceException: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=<the-key>: (401) Login Required in /home/flav/projects/.../google-api-php-client/src/io/apiREST.php on line 86

Call Stack:
    0.0003     252600   1. {main}() /home/flav/projects/.../gcal-api.php:0
    0.0202    1769344   2. EventsServiceResource->insert() /home/flav/projects/.../gcal-api.php:38
    0.0202    1770288   3. apiServiceResource->__call() /home/flav/projects/.../google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php:493
    0.0206    1781864   4. apiREST::execute() /home/flav/projects/.../google-api-php-client/src/service/apiServiceResource.php:187
    0.2342    1794848   5. apiREST::decodeHttpResponse() /home/flav/projects/.../google-api-php-client/src/io/apiREST.php:56
```

How to fix this?

Oh, and on the google API console, I have two values for `Redirect URIs:`, `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` and `http://localhost`, which one should I use for `oauth2_redirect_uri`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be caused by several things. my 2 cents:

Do you have several calendars registered? Maybe your calendar  which you'd like to insert events into isn't the "primary" (=default?) calendar (or your Oauth cred data refer to a different calendar).
If so, replace this line

```
$service->events->insert('primary', $event);
```

with

```
$calendar_id = "somelongstring@group.calendar.google.com"; //look this up from calendar /settings calendar details settings page at the bottom
$service->events->insert($calendar_id, $event);
```

The calendar id is a bit hard to find...look it up. You can find it, for example, on your google account home page /calendar /gear symbol /settings / click calendar-name / calendar details settings page,  at the bottom.

My redirect url (for a web app, though) points to the .php page that issued the oauth request. If authenticated I define another redirect, this time my own. Confusing? yes, but it works for me.